# newgrp asks for a password

Tags: security, login, password, group, history

I don't understand why `newgrp` prompts me for a password when I want to change my group. 
I don't even know what password it is asking for,
but it is certainly not mine (user clime).

```
$ id
uid=500(clime) gid=501(www) groups=501(www),500(clime) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ newgrp clime
Password:       <--- huh?!
```

My system is CentOS 6.3.

Comment: what do you mean by "change my group"?  Are you trying to log in to a group or are you trying to add your account to another group?

Comment: i am trying to log into group clime there

Comment: This question does not seem to be a duplicate of the one it's supposed to be a duplicate of.  I have seen this problem occur when people just try to add users to a group by adding them in /etc/group.  The users have to be added to a group with the usermod command.

Answer (score 4):

`newgrp` is a vestigial command from the days when the kernel would only keep track of one group at a time, so if you were a member in more than one, you had to use this command to switch groups.  If you are not listed as being a member of the group, the group may be assigned a password that you can enter to switch to it.  That is what you are being prompted for.

Comment: but i am a member of the group, see `groups` in my id output.

Comment: It is still used for those systems that have limited numbers of groups too!

Comment: @psusi: but you are otherwise right that I don't need newgrp anymore (at least on my home computer). At work we have still some older systems that needs it. I didn't realize it has changed.

Comment: `newgrp` isn't entirely obsolete. It allows you to switch your primary group still.

Comment: one can remove password requirement via `gpasswd -r groupname`

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov, the group already has no password, which means you can not switch to the group with any password.  The prompt is misleading and nothing you give it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure which group exactly you talk about, but in my case IIRC: `newgrp groupname`  asked for password, after I run `gpasswd -r groupname`, `newgrp groupname` went through, not asking for pass. Linux Mint system.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov, doesn't work for me on Debian.  It still asks for a password.  Are you *in* the group?  If so then it should never ask for the password.

Comment: @psusi, hi, sorry; got back to it today to settle. I might had been incorrect in my comment above; my reperformance today with other group and slightly different Linux Mint failed. I was able to set password to the group with `sudo gpasswd groupname`, next `newgrp groupname`  "accepted" new password.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, you might not realize it but there is a passwd field in the `/etc/group` file.  This field is either NULL (i.e. ::) or a STAR (i.e. `*`) is placed there.  I suspect in your case the latter for this group, that a star (i.e. `*`)  is placed in the passwd file.  Thus with the group entry having what the system sees as a non-null password entry in the group file the `newgrp` command will respond as is appropriate.

Comment: There is `x` instead of `*` but I guess it can have the same meaning.

Comment: Yes that is the case, basically if the field is non-NULL the `newgrp` program will request a password.  I guess `x` is another good filler character.

Comment: even after removing that `x`, newgrp still asks for password. I have set the password using gpasswd so at least I can switch now.

Comment: On RedHat-based systems there is a **/etc/gshadow**. Like **/etc/passwd** the `x` just denotes that there is an existing entry in the shadow-file (which in turn contains the hashed password. `gconv` will create a missing gshadow-entry and create that `x`.

Answer (score -5):

newgrp (1) alters two files, /etc/passwd and /etc/group. Both need root privileges to modify.

Comment: why doesn't it then require su(do) instead of implicitly authenticating you as root?

Comment: No, `newgrp` does not alter any files.

Comment: newgrp alters NO files.....